# Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined Get @input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass my Get method from my parent component to my child component to display the data but I get an error I don't understand.

the error comes from my service

here is the error **Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined**

thanks in advance.

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child [arrayList]="getDetails()"></app-child>
```

**parents.component.ts**

```
public array: any[] = [];

getRoute() {
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: Param) => {
  this.id = params.get('id');
  this.material = params.get('matos'); 
 }
}

getDetails() {
 this.service.get(this.id, this.material).subscribe((data:any[]) => {
 this.array.push(data); 
 }
}
```

**parent.service**

```
get(id: string, material:string) {
 let material = this.str(material:string);*
return this.get<any>(url+id+material);

str(material) {
 return material.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+material.substr(1);
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() arrayList: any[] = [];
```

Comment: in child component you use `@Input() arrayList:any[]=[]` (note: write an space between `app-child` and `[arrayList]` in parent)

Comment: Fortunately, you're safe from the infinite loop due to the undefined Error.
```
get(id: string, material:string) {
 let material = this.str(material:string);*
return this.get<any>(url+id+material);
```

Pease have a look at the `get` method in your parent.service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several glitches in your code, first in child component add input decorator, so that it accepts the input i.e

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() arrayList: any;
```

**parents.component.html**

In parents component you are passing `getDetails()` method to input which will always be undefined since its not returning anything, try to pass `array` list in which you are pushing the data

```
<app-child [arrayList]="array"></app-child>
```

Comment: yes I forgot the @input but if I pass array when I console.log(arrayList) in child component I have empty array why ?

Comment: console log `array` inside `getDetails()` method in parent and see if it has records or not

Comment: I still have the problem of charAt in my service

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @herve you can console log `material` value in `get` method inside your service to make sure material value actually is passed or not.

Comment: nothing is displayed I just have the charAt error, yesterday everything worked fine when I coded it since I use @Input it gives me the error

Comment: @herve you can print `material` inside `getRoute()` method just to confirm if you are getting the route value or not

Comment: Don't need to pass function rather pass data only. That's why it's called data binding.

Comment: I have nothing but when I coded yesterday everything was working fine

Comment: @herve forget about yesterday everyday is a new day :) try to debug today check if the `material` has value from route or not if yes then check inside the methods where you are passing the material where it lost

Comment: I solved my problem by going back and forth until it worked